# Blockchain sync ongoing, apparently reached top block, what is happening?

Tags: go-ethereum, fast-sync

I've installed Ethereum Wallet on a Windows 10 machine and I am now syncing the blockchain with geth --fast --cache 1024. It seems to have downloaded practically all blocks, as eth.syncing returns

```
{
  currentBlock: 3439728,
  highestBlock: 3439874,
  knownStates: 7808,
  pulledStates: 3352,
  startingBlock: 3439692
}
```

But I'm still getting countless lines like

```
I0329 15:02:25.506146 eth/downloader/downloader.go:966] imported   4 state entries in 213.959ms: processed 9882, pending at least 12191
```

and balance still does not show even if the transaction happened in an already processed block. So:

- I assume the balance does not show because the blockchain "states" are still unsynced. Is this correct?
- What are these "state entries" and how do they relate to a block?
- How long will the sync take (already going on for one day)? At least, am I at 1%, 50% or 99%?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Related https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/24667/why-is-my-ether-balance-0-in-geth-even-though-the-sync-is-nearly-complete

Answer (score 1):

> I assume the balance does not show because the blockchain "states" are still unsynced. Is this correct?

Yes

> How long will the sync take (already going on for one day)? At least, am I at 1%, 50% or 99%?

I had exactly your problem. Syncing stopped progress when I reached few hundreds last blocks. Finally I found that problem is my computer timing and I should solve that with enabling network time synchronization!
You can follow [this guide](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-manage-time-servers-windows-10) to enable it on Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

That is normal syncing process. There are 2 stages in the syncing process. Your node is at 2nd stage.

There is no issue on the process and nothing related with Windows.

You can find a detailed explanation of the 2 stages of syncing process here (answer by Greg Jeanmart):
[ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/82053/syncing-keeps-behind-the-blockchain](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/82053/syncing-keeps-behind-the-blockchain)